# Java android VPN SocketChannel that runs through proxy

Tags: java, android, sockets, proxy, vpn

So I've been trying to make a global proxy on Android v > 24, because Android removed programmatically adding global proxies in version 24+. So the only way to currently set a proxy is by changing it manually for wifi, and it wont work with 4g. So my idea was to make a VPN that runs only on the Android, client and server, and runs all the packets through a proxy which is external. The VPN seems to work and my proxy works perfectly, but I can't seem to get the VPN client to run through the proxy. Here's an example of the TCP client creating the SocketChannel.

```
SocketChannel outputChannel = SocketChannel.open();
outputChannel.configureBlocking(false);
vpnService.protect(outputChannel.socket());

try{
    outputChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(destinationAddress, destinationPort));
}
```

This code seems to work to go directly to the website but there doesn't seem to be a way to proxy this. I have tried this method: https://github.com/cobratbq/ProxiedSocketChannel but that doesn't work for some reason. I have tried this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(new InetSocketAddress("PROXY.COM", 8080);
SocketChannel outputChannel = socket.getChannel();
outputChannel.configureBlocking(false);
vpnService.protect(socket);

try{
    outputChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(destinationAddress, destinationPort));
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. All help is appreciated. If you have any questions, need more information, or if I didn't explain well enough please comment.

I'm using this code if you need more reference. - TCPOutput.java
https://github.com/hexene/LocalVPN